# Canot save post if any meta box was empty

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox

I need to dont save new post from custom post type if any meta box empty.

So we must check the meta if empty, we mus show me

" You must fill all meta box value before save post"

else if all meta box was fill, we can save post.

How can do that

Comment: Any code, research or something that you have tried? At least the metabox and custom field code would be useful to may be answer the question.

Comment: i need to save post if all custom meta box was inter :)

Comment: You can hook the `wp_insert_post_data` filter and add a default for that field if you wish? Or use some JS to detect when the `Save/Publish` button is clicked and prevent it working if a certain field is empty?

Comment: can you get me example or edit in my code above ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use `jQuery`.  Add the below code to any JS file that you include in the admin area.

As you haven't given very much information above I don't know a couple of things, so you'll need to amend this example slightly -

- Change `your-post-type` to the slug of the post type for which this metabox exists. If it's the default Post then it'll just be `post`.
- Change `'#field-name'` to the correct ID of your field.  To find this out, check the source of your page.

The code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var post_type = $('#post_type').val();      

    if(post_type === 'your-post-type'){

        $('input#publish').on('click', function(e){

            var myVal = $('#field-name').val();

            if(yourMetaField === ''){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('You must fill all meta box value before save post');
            }

        });

    }

});
```